# UIScrollView bouncing issue from top Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, constraints

> UIScrollView

```
view.addSubview(scrollView)

    scrollView.adopGradientColor()
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.bounces = false

    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

> UIView inside ScrollView

```
scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

    contentView.adopGradientColor()
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 650).isActive = true
```

> I am getting some background colors from top instead of image
>   [image: screenshot of issue]
>
> Here is image implementation

```
contentView.addSubview(backGroundImageView)

    backGroundImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    backGroundImageView.contentMode   = .scaleAspectFill

    backGroundImageView.alpha = 0.5
    backGroundImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "WelcomeBGImage")

    backGroundImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints                           = false

    backGroundImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive              = true
    backGroundImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive      = true
    backGroundImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive    = true

    backGroundImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive               = true
```

> this issue is only on small device like iPhone SE, on big screen showing image on top
>   [image: iphone 8 screen i want like this on iphone se screen as well]

Comment: So you want to have the image as in the second screenshot where the status bar is covered as well

Comment: yes, this is issue only small size screen iPhone SE and the second screenshot is iPhone 8 where works fine.